# Calculate Overlap of two time ranges in Google Sheets (or Excel)

Tags: excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I have a start and an end time for a task and now need to figure out, how much time of that task falls within a specific time range (because rates are different at different times of the day).

I.e:

```
Time task was running:
Start (Cell A4): 20:00
End (Cell B4): 01:00

Range of interest:
Start (Cell C4): 23:00
End (Cell D4): 06:00

Result:
Overlap (Cell E4): 02:00
```

I did come up with a formula that works most of the time:

```
E4 = max(Max(0, Min(B4+(A4>B4), D4+(C4>D4)) - Max(A4, C4)),0)
```

however, this does not take the case into consideration, where the start of the task occurs before the end of the range of interest, i.e:

```
Time task was running:
Start (Cell A4): 05:00
End (Cell B4): 13:00

Range of interest:
Start (Cell C4): 23:00
End (Cell D4): 06:00

Result:
Overlap (Cell E4): 01:00 (should be, but is 0:00)
```

An adjusted formula that will capture this case as well, is this:

```
E4 = (MAX(0,MIN(D4+(C4>D4),B4+(A4>B4))-MAX(C4,A4))+MAX(0,(MIN(D4,B4+(A4>B4))-A4)*(C4>D4))+MAX(0,MIN(D4+(C4>D4),B4+0)-C4)*(A4>B4))
```

But I feel that there should be a more elegant solution to deal with circular ranges, i.e hours that wrap around.

Any hints?

Comment: Without the date included cell B4 could just as well be 29 hours later than A4

Comment: @P.b technically, yes, but from the way the form is used, it will always be within a 24hr period.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```cpp
=LET(min_end,MIN(B4,D4),
     max_start,MAX(A4-(A4>B4),C4-(C4>D4)),
     (min_end-max_start)*(min_end>max_start))
```

It's essentially subtracting the maximum of the start times from the minimum of the end times. Before the subtraction is performed, the times are adjusted so that if the start time is greater than the end time, it is assumed to be on the day before.

If the times do not overlap, i.e. the subtraction returns a negative value, the formula returns 0.

Comment: @z That formula using let is certainly more elegant than mine, but it fails when:
task: 05:00 - 00:00 and range: 23:00 - 06:00.

Comment: the overlap is 23:00 - 00:00 so 01:00 which is what the formula returns. Or am I missing something?

Comment: there's also a second overlap from 05:00 - 06:00, so 02:00...

Comment: @RemoPini Your logic is off. Try thinking in dates, like I suggested and you'll see 1 hour is correct

Comment: @P.b Nope, my logic stands: Any work done between 23:00 and 06:00 has a penalty of X. If a task starts at 05:00 and runs until 00:00, it will incur TWO penalties of 1hrs each, one at the beginning of the task run and one at the end. Hours wrap around before AND after any given day. I know for sure, because I'm actually paying that penalty and that is how it is defined.

Comment: I get it; I posted a way to cope with that

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses Excel (Office 365)

```
=LET(x,LAMBDA(s,e,
              MOD(s+SEQUENCE(1+((e<s)+e-s)*24,,0)/24,1)),
SUM(N(x(A4,B4)=TOROW(x(C4,D4))))/24)
```

The LAMBDA `x` is a function to create a sequence of hours from start to end timevalue in steps of hours.

`x(A4,B4)` creates a first sequence. `x(C4,D4)` creates the second, which we transpose (TOROW). If we now SUM the hours of the two arrays that equal you get your overlap.

I divided the result by 24, so you can format it as time to show the hour difference.

Or when you store name `X` in the name manager and in refers to paste `LAMBDA(s,e,MOD(s+SEQUENCE(1+((e<s)+e-s)*24,,0)/24,1))`

You could use `=SUM(N(X(A4,B4)=TOROW(X(C4,D4))))/24`

I think this image helps explain the calculation logic:

[image]

Comment: @RemoPini let me know if that works for you.